# rails 3.1 rc6 asset pipeline: js and css won't compile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

i upgraded to rails rc6, and my javascripts and css files won't compile. there is no error, nothing, they just don't show up. works fine with rc5. this is getting really frustrating, as with every 3.1 rc my asset pipeline tends to break.

Comment: Can you show both your application.js and your application.css ? (assets subdirectories)

Comment: did you file an issue in GitHub? More details will help resolving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was/is actually a spree bug (current master tree):
https://github.com/spree/spree/commit/01e46fd151564dce1d6244d41c66b51be821fb3c#L1R73
forked it and fixed it.